# How do I increase blank space padding between header options react

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to figure out how to match my figma design to my react web app, I am trying to increase the blank spacing between the options in the header does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Figma image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXGiA.jpg

Current web app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXGiA.jpg

Code:

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';
import LinkButton from '../../../components/LinkButton';
import { theme } from '../../../styles/theme';

export const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 71.5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 80px 38px 0 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
`;

export const Logo = styled.img`
  margin-left: 43px;
  height: 73px;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

export const NavBar = styled.nav`
  margin-right: 43px;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5px;
  a {
    margin-left: 57px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.font3.new};
    font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight.med_700};
  }
  a:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
`;

export const NavButton = styled(LinkButton)`
  margin-left: 52px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.font3.new};
  font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight.med_700};
`;

export const customStyles = {
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, .9)',
  },
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '460px',
    height: '718px',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    background: '#111',
    border: `4px solid ${theme.colors.modal.border}`,
    borderRadius: '15px',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },
};
```

Comment: A live runnable [mcve] would be much easier to debug than a picture.  With your browser's debugging tools you can observe and adjust the styling of your HTML, which would help you determine what changes to make to the code.

Answer (score 0):

it can be many ways you can do it by giving fix width to the list in header or using grid system like give column to each I think you should do it with padding. Give the padding to a tag on x-axis it will be the good option.

considering your a tag as each item in navbar

```
 a {
//added code
padding-right:40px;
padding-right:40px;

margin-left: 57px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.font3.new};
font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontWeight.med_700};
```

}